# Is there a Delegate which isn't a MulticastDelegate in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, multicastdelegate

I think the answer is NO? If there isn't, why do we have separated `Delegate` and `MulticastDelegate` classes? Maybe it's again because of "some other .NET languages"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EDIT: I *thought* this was part of ECMA 335, but I can't see it in there anywhere.

You can't create such a delegate type in C#, but you can in IL:

```
.class public auto ansi sealed Foo
       extends [mscorlib]System.Delegate
{
    // Body as normal
}
```

The C# compiler has no problems using such a delegate:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo f = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
        f("hello");
    }
}
```

But the CLR does when it tries to load it:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Foo' from assembly 'Foo, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it cannot inherit directly from the delegate class.
>      at Test.Main()

Basically the Delegate/MulticastDelegate separation is an historical accident. I believe that early alpha/beta versions did make the distinction, but it proved too confusing and generally not useful - so now *every* delegate derives from MulticastDelegate.

(Interestingly, the C# specification only mentions MulticastDelegate once, in the list of types which can't be used as generic constraints.)

Comment: What does PEVerify say on that assembly with `Foo`?

Comment: @leppie: Haven't tried yet. Feel free to do so :) (I just ran ildasm on a "normal" declaration to get the IL, then doctored it and re-ilasmed.)

Comment: I used ilasm/ildasm to a test delegate and got the expected result in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why the CLR enforces this constraint? There have been several times when I want an event to only *be able* to have one subscriber. This is possible by specifying your own `add`/`remove` but having a non-multicast delegate would make this simpler.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: No idea, I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 2):

No, the CLR does not allow that.

I recall something that they wanted to expose `Delegate` directly, but that was never needed.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't, because all delegates must naturally be able to be `Delegate.Combine`ed. Delegate is there simply to wrap the non-multicasting functionality into a base class.

Comment: Even if every delegate had a single method pointer and target, Delegate.Combine could be implemented just fine: simply create an object with two fields of appropriate delegate type, which runs them sequentially.  Using MulticastDelegates may offer a performance advantage in situations where delegates with a large number of sub-delegates are run frequently, but seldom involved with Combine and Remove, but I would be surprised if it yields better performance in more typical situations.  Personally, I wish that there had been a mutable "event list" type, perhaps a struct with a single field...

Comment: ...of type Object, which could hold either a null, a single delegate, or an array of delegates, and which included a methods to invoke that field as appropriate as well as perform thread-safe Add and Remove operations (using Interlocked.CompareExchange); the invocation methods should offer a choice of stopping at the first exception, or letting all handlers run and throwing a BundledException with a list of all exceptions that occurred while running them. Having the event list keep delegates references, rather than a list of methods and targets would eliminate quirks in the existing approach.

Answer (score 1):

System.MuticastDelegate is derived from System.Delegate.
Each level within the delegate hierarchy provides a different set of services. System.Delegate is a container of the data for what method to call on a particular object. With System.MulticastDelegate comes the additional capability of not only invoking a method on a single object, but on a collections of objects. This enables multiple subscribers to an event.

Not sure, i have answered your question.

Comment: While that sounds appropriate, it doesn't explain why GetInvocationList (clearly about invoking *multiple* methods) is part of Delegate, and not MulticastDelegate...