# Why delegate types are derived from MulticastDelegate class why not it directly derive from Delegate class?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, multicastdelegate

I have a very basic question regarding delegate types. I compared the memebers of `Delegate` and `MulticastDelegate` classes in object browser and I couldn't find any new additional member present in `MulticastDelegate`.

I also noticed that the `Delegate` class has `GetInvocationList` virtual method. So I assume that the `Delegate` class should have the capability to hold references to multiple methods. If my assumption is correct, I wonder why not custom delegate types directly derive from the `Delegate` class instead of `MulticastDelegate` class.

Not sure what I am missing here. Please help me understand the difference.

Comment: Dupe: [is-there-a-delegate-which-isnt-a-multicastdelegate-in-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711118/is-there-a-delegate-which-isnt-a-multicastdelegate-in-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 14):

Basically the split of `Delegate` and `MulticastDelegate` is for historical reasons. Originally there were going to be delegates which *couldn't* be combined and ones which could... but that turned out not to be a useful distinction. Apparently that was only discovered when it was a bit too late to rip `MulticastDelegate` out of the framework/CLR.

From CLR via C#, 3rd edition:

> The `System.MulticastDelegate` class is derived from `System.Delegate`, which is itself derived from `System.Object`. The reason why there are two delegate classes is historical and unfortunate; there should be just one delegate class in the FCL. 
> Sadly, you need to be aware of both of these classes because even though all delegate types you create have `MulticastDelegate` as a base class, you'll occasionally manipulate your delegate types by using methods defined by the `Delegate` class instead of the `MulticastDelegate` class. [...]