# C# System.Delegate.Combine

Tags: c#

I have a bit of confusion regarding static Combine( ) provided in System.Delegate( )

This method returns a System.Delegate type and its purpose is to combine invocation lists of multiple delegates.

But if a delegate is supposed to refer to a single method, and a multicast delegate is supposed to hold reference to multiple methods, then how is the return type of Combine justified as just a System.Delegate?

I think I am missing something here.

Can someone please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Dupe: [why-delegate-types-are-derived-from-multicastdelegate-class-why-not-it-directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833053/why-delegate-types-are-derived-from-multicastdelegate-class-why-not-it-directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All delegates have the capability of being multicast.  Consider `Delegate.GetInvocationList`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but Multicast Delegates inherit from Delegates... so while it returns an object that is of the Type Delegate, you may be able to cast it to a multicast delegate....

Answer (score -1):

System.Delegate is abstract, so there is never an instance of System.Delegate returned, just instances of concrete types () derived from System.MulticastDelegate. To my knowledge there is no type that is a Delegate that can only hold a reference to one method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: System.MulticastDelegate is also declared abstract on msdn

Comment: My mistake, I meant to say "just concrete types derived from System.MulticastDelegate". Thanks!