# Multicast delegate C#

Tags: c#, delegates

Am studying about delegates. As I read. I learned that adding more than one function in a delegate is called multicast delegate. Based on that I wrote a program. Here two functions (AddNumbers and MultiplyNumbers) I added in the MyDelegate.
Is the below program is an example for multicast delegate ?.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate(int a, int b);
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyDelegate myDel = new MyDelegate(AddNumbers);
        myDel += new MyDelegate(MultiplyNumbers);
        myDel(10, 20);
    }

    public void AddNumbers(int x, int y)
    {
        int sum = x + y;
        MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
    }

    public void MultiplyNumbers(int x, int y)
    {
        int mul = x * y;
        MessageBox.Show(mul.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: This question might be better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Dupe: [simple-delegate-delegate-vs-multicast-delegates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192219/simple-delegate-delegate-vs-multicast-delegates)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's an example of a multicast delegate. Note that instead of

```
new MyDelegate(AddNumbers)
```

you can typically say just

```
AddNumbers
```

because a so-called method group conversion exists that will create the delegate instance for you.

Another thing to note is that your declaration `public delegate void MyDelegate(int a, int b);` does not *have* to reside inside another type (here inside the `MainPage` class). It could be a direct member of the namespace (since it's a type). But of course it's perfectly valid to "nest" it inside a class, as you do, for reasons similar to the reason why you create nested classes.

Comment: a method group conversion only occurs when we have assigned a method thats overloaded, and at least one overload matches the delegate. In this case there is no method group conversion.

Comment: @Freeman I was suggesting he changed his code into this: `MyDelegate myDel = AddNumbers; myDel += MultiplyNumbers;` If he did that, a method group conversion would happen to instantiate his type `MyDelegate`. It's a method group conversion even if the "group" of overloads (including generic overloads) consists of just one overload.

Comment: if you provide me a reference to some documentation i will believe you. Until then i will stick to the original ECMA documentation that states my previous comment. There must be a method group with the same name in the same class / struct so we can have a method group conversion.

Comment: @Freeman If you don't think `MyDelegate myDel = AddNumbers;` (with names referring to the question) is a method group conversion, then what would it be then? Read the C# Language Specification where the relevant section begins: _An implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from a method group (§7.1) to a compatible delegate type. Given a delegate type D and an expression E that is classified as a method group, an implicit conversion exists from E to D if [...]_ Also try saying `var x = AddNumbers;`. The compiler will respond `CS0815: Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable`

Comment: Nine years later: With C# 10.0, the statement `var x = AddNumbers;` is no longer a compile-time error. However, it will be `Action<int, int>` that will be picked as the type for `x`, not `MainPage.MyDelegate`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually *all* delegates in C# are MulticastDelegates, even if they only have a single method as target. (Even anonymous functions and lambdas are MulticastDelegates even though they by definition have only single target.)

`MulticastDelegate` is simply the base class for all kinds of function or method references in C#, whether they contain one or more targets.

So this:

```
MyDelegate myDel = new MyDelegate(AddNumbers);
```

Sets `myDel` to a `MulticastDelegate` with a single target. But this line:

```
myDel += new MyDelegate(MultiplyNumbers);
```

Updates `myDel` to a `MulticastDelegate` with two targets.

Comment: Related: [Is there a Delegate which isn't a MulticastDelegate in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4711118/1497596)

Answer (score 1):

**Multicast delegates is one of the feature of delegates, it wraps the reference of multiple methods and calls it sequentially and it is also known as Delegate Chaining.**

**Below is the example of multicast delegates.**

```
    // Declare Delegates
public delegate void MultiCast(int num1, int num2);

class Program
{
    public void Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
    }
    public  void Sub(int num1, int num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
    }
    public  void Mul(int num1, int num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MultiCast del1, del2, del3, multAddDel, multSubDel;
        del1 = new Program().Add;
        del2 = new Program().Sub;
        del3 = new Program().Mul;

    //`There are three ways to define the multicast delegate.`

        //1 way

        //Adding delegates 
        multAddDel = del1 + del2 + del3;
        multAddDel(10, 10);
        //Removing Delegates
        multSubDel = multAddDel - del3;
        multSubDel(10, 10);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Second Way");

        //2 way

        MultiCast multAddDel1 = null;
        //Adding delegates 
        multAddDel1 += del1;
        multAddDel1 += del2;
        multAddDel1 +=  del3;
        multAddDel1(10, 10);
        //Removing Delegates
        multAddDel1 -= del3;
        multAddDel1(10, 10);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Third Way");

        //3 way

        MultiCast multAddDel2 = null;
        //Adding delegates 
        multAddDel2 = (MultiCast)Delegate.Combine(multAddDel2, del1);
        multAddDel2 = (MultiCast)Delegate.Combine(multAddDel2, del2);
        multAddDel2 = (MultiCast)Delegate.Combine(multAddDel2, del3);
        multAddDel2(10, 10);

        //Removing Delegates
        multAddDel2 = (MultiCast)
            Delegate.Remove(multAddDel2, del3);

        multAddDel2(10, 10);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```