# Use case for Delegate class

Tags: c#, delegates

As the `MulticastDelegate` is ruling delegate class of .NET I would like to ask, are there any use cases for using `Delegate` class?

I mean if I had a variable of type `Delegate` and another one of type `MulticastDelegate`, different method overriddes (e.g `GetInvocationList`) will be called but if every single-programmer defined delegate inherits from `MulticastDelegate` what could be a point for using `Delegate` class?

And if as I assume there is none, shouldn't it be marked with `ObsoleteAttribute` with comment to use `MulticastDelegate` instead?

Or shouldn't compiler silently change "`Delegate variable1;`" to "`MulticastDelegate variable1;`"?

Comment: You should virtually never be using the `Delegate` or `MulticastDelegate` types directly.  Any specific delegates defined will actually be of both types (a `MulticastDelegate` is a sub-type of `Delegate`) but you should only ever refer to delegates by their specific type, with a defined signature.

Comment: but what about generalized list of delegates for example I would use List<MulticastDelegate> there as I don't know method signatures

Comment: @user1121956: What benefit does that give you over `List<Delegate>`?

Comment: @user1121956 If you don't know the method signatures what do you plan to do with the delegates?  You can't invoke them as you don't know what their parameters are, and you won't be able to use the return value because you won't know if it has one, or what it might be.

Comment: Dupe: [is-there-a-delegate-which-isnt-a-multicastdelegate-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711118/is-there-a-delegate-which-isnt-a-multicastdelegate-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not obsolete, and I see no reason to mark it as such.

If the only members you need are provided by `Delegate`, why would you use `MulticastDelegate`?

In my experience `Delegate` comes up much more often in the .NET API as "any delegate" than `MulticastDelegate` does. For example:

- [`LambdaExpression.Compile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928.aspx)
- [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)

It's definitely only due to historical accident that the two classes both exist, but that's no reason to deprecate uses of just `Delegate`.

Additionally, you write:

> I mean if I had a variable of type Delegate and another one of type MulticastDelegate, different method overloads (e.g GetInvocationList) will be called

No, [`GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) isn't overloaded. It's [*overridden*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) in `MulticastDelegate`, but not overloaded. Oh, and note the return type of that method - it's `Delegate[]`, not `MulticastDelegate[]`.

Comment: sure it's overridden not overloaded, I mistyped this in hurryness, stupid error XD

Comment: and that's exactly my point, if I call GetInvocationList of MulticastDelegate type I will get different result than Delegate type and it will be error prone for program which would like to do `for (int i ...) List<Delegate>[i].DynamicInvoke(arg_list[i])`

Comment: @user1121956: No, you *won't* get a different result, precisely *because* it's overridden. The `MulticastDelegate` implementation will be called anyway. `foo.GetInvocationList()` will execute the exact same code whether the compile-time type of `foo` is `MulticastDelegate` or `Delegate`. If you believe otherwise, you need to revise your understanding of how virtual methods work.

Comment: oh lol, you're perfectly right, in the amok of thinking I forgot that all delegates are Multicast anyway, thank you :)